# Accessible Continuous Integration

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, accessibility

I am looking for a continuous integration suite that is accessible to blind users. I cannot seem to find one. TeamCity looks really nice but has no accessibility support. Is there a blind-accessible continuous integration solution?

Answer (score 2):

Going from my own experience here, CruiseControl seems pretty good. I've only used the .NET version, which comes with a task tray icon for Windows, so I'm not sure whether the other versions have that. But the web interface, which I assume is universal, is accessible. I've been using it with NVDA (Non-Visual Desktop Access) v2012.3.1. That's the only one I've tried so far, I'm afraid. But I hope this helps.